# Sort sencha touch dataview list

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a Ext.dataview.List that is linked to a store that is sorted by date DESC.

When I run the app the list is in the correct date sorted order.

When I add a new item it always gets added to the bottom of the list rather than in the correct sorted order. When I refresh the app the order is sorted correctly again.

I am adding an item to the list:

```
var myStore = Ext.getStore('myStore');
myStore.add(model);
myStore.sync();
```

View:

```
Ext.create('Ext.dataview.List', {
    fullscreen: true,
    itemTpl: '{title}',
    store: Ext.getStore('myStore')
});
```

How do I add an item to the store and get the list to sort itself so that the item is in the correct place?

Comment: Probably its not reading/saving the date file correctly, did you check that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using:

```
myStore.sort();
myStore.sort('date', 'DESC');
```

They did not work. This fixed the issue though:

```
myStore.data.sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually sort the store after adding the model. Try this:

```
var myStore = Ext.getStore('myStore');
myStore.add(model);
myStore.sync();
//Also note that the sync() method is only when you're using a localStorage proxy

myStore.sort();
```

or

```
myStore.sort('date', 'DESC');
```

Comment: I have tried a couple of variations of calling sort on the store. And it doesn't seem to take effect. I just though could it be to do with the fact i'm not destroying the list view when adding the new item. It is sitting in the DOM already?